# COSMOS DB Find object within an object based on a value

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have multiple JSON objects within items in COSMOS DB. For example:

```
"Fruit": {
    "Apples": 200,
    "Oranges": 130,        
    "Strawberries": {
        "Small": 30,
        "Large": "Finished"
    }
    
"Fruit": {
        "Apples": 78,
        "Oranges": 90,        
        "Strawberries": {
            "Small": 10,
            "Large": 30
        }
```

And I want to return all fruit where large is "Finished". So in this example just the first object would be returned. I imagine this is straightforward to achieve but I haven't managed to do this. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple where clause would do,

```
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE c.Fruit.Strawberries.Large = "Finished"
```